# How can I make my site stop adding <p> tags in textareas?

Tags: input-formats

For a current project I have a content type’s textarea set to Full HTML. But where I’ve added a `<span>` tag, Drupal will go ahead and enclose it within a `<p>` tag which is definitely not what I want!

It’s also adding an empty `<p>` tag at the bottom of said container.

How and where can that be turned off? Where is the mechanism or module that is doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe you need to disable the "Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. `<br>` and `<p>`)" filter on your Full HTML text format.

This can be done by navigating to Configuration > Content authoring > Text formats and editors, then editing the Full HTML configuration and un-checking the box for "Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. `<br>` and `<p>`)" under "Enabled filters". Assuming this is Drupal 8 anyway. Drupal 7 has the same setting but the exact location might be different.

Comment: thanks Joe!, why i was just watching one of your video tuts this a.m......